# Animation Nodes: Create a custom node

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I have created a fairly complicated node tree in Animation Nodes. There are various parameters of different types that I set on various different nodes.

To make this easier for others to use, I'd like to create a single node, with all the inputs named, so that there's just one place to set all the input parameters. This would look similar to how you get a node group in the materials editor or compositor. AFAIK, Animation nodes does not have node groups.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In animation nodes, Groups are a kind of subprogram, like Loops or Scripts. To add one, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Subprograms* > *Group*. Then, you can name your group and connect up your grouped nodes to the inputs and outputs of the Group. Here is a gif of this from the [Animation Nodes Docs](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/group.html):

[image]

You can invoke your group with an *Add Subprogram* node.

Comment: Many thanks for this - I've just tried it and I'm getting an error of "'Object Instancer' must not be in a subprogram". Any suggestions on how I work around this ?

Comment: For now I've taken the instancer out of the group - it means my inputs are now splits across two nodes, rather than just the one group input. That's not great but it's better than it was when I posted.

Comment: @DavidGilson Object Instancer can not be used inside loops or Groups. To be able to give you a workaround, you have to give us more details. Maybe ask another question if needed.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Thank you - Instead of passing arguments to the object instancer into the group, I've passed the object list it creates into the group. It seemed the best way to deal with my set up.

Comment: Thank you, teacher.